# Using an AsyncTask to call a Handler. Is this good practice?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, handler, runnable

I want to know whether a practice I am using is correct or not? Please have a look!

I am using an AsyncTask to call a Handler to animate (increment gradually over time) the progress in a ProgressBar.

I could only use Handler to animate it but I needed to animate multiple ProgressBars using the same Handler. I did not find it possible to pass a paramerer "ProgressBar" to a Handler, nor did declaring a global variable (maybe array?) looked clean.

So I pass the ProgressBar into an AsyncTask as a parameter, and then within the AsyncTask, I have defined the Handler which manipulates the passed ProgressBar using the method of AsyncTask called publishProgress(int). So Each call to AsyncTask is effectively equal to serving the Handler a unique passed ProgressBar.

I am including a stripped down code which shows the structure:

```
public class animateProgress extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<ArrayList>, Integer, Boolean> {
    ProgressBar pb;
    int incrementProgress;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(ArrayList<ArrayList>... arrayLists) {
        ArrayList<ArrayList> gotArrayList = arrayLists[0]; //get passed arraylist

        ArrayList<ProgressBar> alP = gotArrayList.get(1);
        pb = alP.get(0); // REFERENCE TO PROGRESSBAR IS ACQUIRED HERE.
        scoreCounter.postDelayed(scoreCounterUpdate, 0);
        return null;
    }

    private Handler scoreCounter = new Handler();
    private Runnable scoreCounterUpdate = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            if (MY_LOGIC_THAT_PROGRESS_SHOULD_INCREMENT) {
                publishProgress(incrementProgress);

            }
            if (MY_LOGIC_THAT_WE_SHOULD_EXIT) {
                scoreCounter.removeCallbacks(scoreCounterUpdate);
            } else {
                scoreCounter.postDelayed(this, 50);
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        pb.incrementProgressBy(values[0]);
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

The code works perfectly but my concern is that I think I should either not use AsyncTask or not use Handler.
Also, I think that doInBackground() should theoretically finish as soon as I call scoreCounter.postDelayed(), and so should the whole AsyncTask. But in reality, the publishProgress() called by handler many seconds later still works. This is confusing.